# Comparision of local and remote maven release artifacts

Tags: maven-2

Is it possible to tune maven to compare checksums of local release artifacts with checksums of release artifacts from remote repository and update artifacts with mismatched checksum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

Maven will check the checksum of a release only once: When the artifact is downloaded for the first time. Since the artifact can be found in your local repo, Maven will not try to download it (or its checksum) again. Therefore, it can't notice checksum changes.

You must find a different way to notice which checksums/artifacts changed on the remote server and delete those artifacts in your local repo.

Note that on release servers, released artifacts (and their checksums) should never change, even if the checksum is wrong. Instead, a new release (with a new, non-snapshot version) should be uploaded to the server to make sure everyone can easily see that something has changed.